# How to update Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 package using powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Appx Package was blocked
because the provided package has the same identity as an already-installed
package but the contents are different. Increment the version number of the
package to be installed, or remove the old package for every user on the
system before installing this package.

Above message is displayed when I update Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 using powershell cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the app before reinstalling if it's the same version.

Comment: I believe you'll then have to increment the version number. You may also be able to make a script that uninstalls, then install the package, but you'll lose your saved data (unless you also save off the data, then reload it).